# Django dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

Tags: python, django

after passing this line of code in my context processor I am getting above error `'notifications.views.Count_Notifications` I am facing this problems for unauthenticated user. I am passing context in context processor for showing few user info in my base.html navbar such as number of notifications, user name etc. here is my code:

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def Count_Notifications(request):
    count_notifications_comment = 0
    count_notifications_author = 0
    blog_author = Blog.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        count_notifications_comment = Notifications.objects.filter(sender=request.user,is_seen=False).count()
        count_notifications_author = Notifications.objects.filter(user=request.user,is_seen_author_noti=False).count()
       
    return {'count_notifications_comment':count_notifications_comment,'count_notifications_author':count_notifications_author,'blog_author':blog_author}
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                 'notifications.views.Count_Notifications'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**console error**

```
updates.update(processor(self.request))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required
[18/Jul/2021 01:03:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 99622
```

Comment: What if you drop the `@login_required`?

Comment: Willem Van Onsem getting this error `AnonymousUser' object is not iterable` if drop the @login_required

Comment: that means that the `request.user` is not authenticated, but you can not use `login_required`, since then it will return a HTTP redirect object, not an empty dictionary.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem then how I will show user info my bas.html nav bar such as number of notifications, user name etc. I need to be pass context in my base.html for showing login user info in nav bar.

Comment: if a user is not logged in, then it makes no sense to display some number of notifications.

Comment: can you share the traceback of the `AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`. It looks like you are iterating over `request.user`, so `{% for ... in request.user %}` for example, which does not make much sense.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem  I am using this in my base.html  `{%if user.is_authenticated %}...my code{%endif %}` I am not using any for loop in my html. After remove `@login_required` I am getting this error `'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`

Comment: can you share the *full* traceback? Without debugging details it is hard to fix the underlying problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `@login_required`, and the user is not authenticated, then it will return a [**`HttpResponseRedirect`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect), not an empty dictionary.

You will thus need to check authentication in your context processor, so:

```
# no login_required
def Count_Notifications(request):
    count_notifications_comment = 0
    count_notifications_author = 0
    blog_author = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        blog_author = Blog.objects.filter(author=request.user)
        count_notifications_comment = Notifications.objects.filter(sender=request.user, is_seen=False).count()
        count_notifications_author = Notifications.objects.filter(user=request.user, is_seen_author_noti=False).count()
       
    return {
        'count_notifications_comment': count_notifications_comment,
        'count_notifications_author':count_notifications_author,
        'blog_author':blog_author
    }
```

Comment: Willem Van Onsem Thanks. That was the issue

Comment: Also I had to delete or comment out `@user_passes_test()`